# A Disabled User in need of Suggestions/Help (UI Question)

Tags: interface, shortcut, pie-menu

I have a minor case if Cerebral Palsy which affects my left hand therefore using some of the keyboard shortcuts are impossible for me to use.  I’m using Blender 2.8.

Just a few Examples of the problem keyboard shortcuts (in Windows)…

Ctrl+Alt+LMB for (Bridging Edgeloops)

Shift+Ctrl+ALT+C for (Set Origin)

I have tried making Macros but they are too limited.

I’m hoping someone has any suggestions,

Comment: Is it convenient to use the ui buttons? All operations done with shortcuts have equivalent ui buttons or selectors

Comment: Georges, If I understand what you are saying, there are UI Buttons/Selectors for every shortcuts. I just have found or seen a list of them yet.

Comment: Ok, for bridging edge loop, let's assume you're already in edit mode, and both edge loops are selected, at the top in 3D View, you'll find the drop-down menu items, among them is Edge, the bridge edge loop is there, also at any time, you can press space bar and wright the name opperation you would like to use

Comment: Also for aligning objects and origins, I created an addon called Easy Align, and included some already existing operations as buttons, I also find shift+ctrl+alt+C very awkward, here's the link: https://blenderartists.org/t/addon-easy-align/685704

Comment: Do you already tried using pie menus in Blender? If that's an option we can easily transfer all the operations to a custom pie menu.

Comment: Are you still able to type? You could use the "Space Menu". In Blender 2.80 Beta it got moved to the F3 button on your keyboard. Press F3, then type the first letters of the function you want to use (e.g. "loop") and select the function in the suggestion list. That's what I do when my left hand cramps due to Multiple Sclerosis.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at programs like [Stroke Plus](https://www.strokesplus.com/). It allows you to add multi-key keyboard shortcuts to mouse gestures,without having to take up more shortcut keys on a already crowded keyboard.
Really almost anything you can do with a keyboard such as type in commands or strings like an email address. You can assign gestures globally or per-program. 
See the video on the home page for a quick explanation. 
I have used this for years to speed up programming.

Answer (score 0):

For setting the origin, I use the drop down menu to the right of the "Object Mode" title/ menu bar. "Snap" /Cursor is just below that, along with many other options.  Each Mode has a set of drop down menu options that do not require shortcuts.  Hope this helps.[image]